# Dynamically generated object property undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this dynamically generated object whose properties displayed `undefined`. I don't seem to understand why it happened.

Pls help.

here is the code.

```
let submittionObject = {};
let submit = {};

let theSubmission = ['english', 'mathematics', 'r1Submitted', 'biology'];

    const theSubmit = theSubmission.map((item, index) => {
    if(item.indexOf('Submitted') !== -1){
        console.log(item.indexOf('Submitted'))
        submit = {...submittionObject, [item]: false};
    }else{
        submit = {...submittionObject,  [`r${index+1}Submitted`]: true};
    }
    return submit;
});



        const {r1Submitted, r2Submitted, r3Submitted, r4Submitted} = theSubmit;
```

The value of the destructured object should be a boolean of `true` or `false` but it instead displayed `undefined`

Comment: What does contain `submittionObject` ?

Comment: what is the value of submittionObject?

Comment: `submittionObject` is an empty Object. Thank you

Comment: @MisbahuAbubakar I added an answer with minimal code of lines. Hope that will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you `console.log(theSubmit)`, you can see that it is an array that contains the objects that contains the properties `r1Submmitted`, `r2Submitted` and so on.

```
[
  { r1Submitted: true },
  { r2Submitted: true },
  { r1Submitted: false },
  { r4Submitted: true }
]
```

This is because `.map()` returns an array

I'm not sure what you want exactly but is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
let theSubmission = ['english', 'mathematics', 'r1Submitted', 'biology'];
let submissionObject = {};
theSubmission.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (item.indexOf('Submitted') !== -1) {
        console.log(item.indexOf('Submitted'))
        submissionObject = { ...submissionObject, [item]: false };
    } else {
        submissionObject = { ...submissionObject, [`r${index + 1}Submitted`]: true };
    }
})

console.log(submissionObject)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are looking for something like this **:**

```js
const theSubmission = ['english', 'mathematics', 'r1Submitted', 'biology'];
const submittionObject = {};

theSubmission.forEach((subject, index) => {
  submittionObject[theSubmission[index]] = (subject.indexOf('Submitted') !== -1) ? true : false;
});

console.log(submittionObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

map returns an array and property 'r1Submitted' and so on does not exist on an array. You will need to loop over the array to find the item with that property on it.

`const r1Submitted  = theSubmit.find(i => i.r1Submitted)`

Answer (score 0):

Return a boolean in the callback. Try this,

```
let submittionObject = {};
let submit = {};

let theSubmission = ['english', 'mathematics', 'r1Submitted', 'biology'];

    const theSubmit = theSubmission.map((item, index) => {
    if(item.indexOf('Submitted') !== -1){
        console.log(item.indexOf('Submitted'))
        item = false;
    }else{
        item = true;
    }
    return item;
  });
```